# Flutter context Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I would like guidance on how to avoid this problem that occurs with some users. It's not a general error.
It seems that flutter disables/dispose the context during my app's initialization flow.
I'm using FutureBuilder in initState.
The screen only loads after the future method finishes calling several routines.
I initialize my Provider in initiState like this:

```
` @override void initState() {       
super.initState();     
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);      
_userDataController = Provider.of<UserDataController>(context, listen: false);        
futureResult = getDataIni();     
}`
```

in my getDataIni method I initialize remote config settings, notifications, etc and call a method from my provider. In some devices it is giving this error when calling the provider method:
`await _userDataController.loadData(context);`

Error:
Null check operator used on a null value
#0 State.context (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:954)#1 _HomePageState.getDataIni.....)#2 _FutureBuilderState._subscribe. (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:628)

I know it's a flutter error and not the provider. But how do I avoid this and guarantee state for the entire application?
My widget is a stateFullWidget.

### I expected context to always be available. As I said the error is not general.

UPDATE
unfortunately the problem is not solved and I don't know what else to do.
If anyone can help me.

Occurs in line:

```
await _userDataController.loadSync(context, signatureController: _signatureController);
```

Error:
Null check operator used on a null value

```
#0 State.context (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:958)#1
_HomePageState.getData (package:appxxxx/pages/home_page.dart:211)<asynchronous suspend>#2
_FutureBuilderState._subscribe.<anonymous close> (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:624)<asynchronous suspend>
```

follows the complete code of the method loaded in the future:

```
Future<bool> getData() async {
    try {
      _abaController = context.read<AbaController>();
      _assinaturaController = context.read<AssinaturaController>();
      var _userDataController = context.read<UserDataController>();
      isOnline = await Conexao.isOnline();

      //test your internet connection online
      if (isOnline == false)
        return Future<bool>.value(false);

      //get current date and time from server
      await DataUtils.loadDateTimeServer();
      //initialize remote config
      await GetIt.I<RemoteConfigService>().loadData();
      ///Checks if app update is mandatory and aborts
      int versaoAppLocal = int.parse((await PackageInfo.fromPlatform()).buildNumber);
      int versaoAppRemoteConfig = GetIt.I<RemoteConfigService>().versaoMinimaApp;

      if (versaoAppLocal < versaoAppRemoteConfig){
        atualizacaoAppObrigatoria = true;
        return Future<bool>.value(false);
      }

      ///Check if the environment is under maintenance and abort
      if (GetIt.I<RemoteConfigService>().isAmbienteEmManutencao){
        isAmbienteEmManutencao = true;
        return Future<bool>.value(false);
      }

      //retrieves instance Firebase auth and sets user logged in provider
      await GetIt.I<AuthService>().init(context);
      //initializes the subscriptions plugin (revenuecat) and sets if the user is a subscriber or not
      await GetIt.I<PurchaseService>().load(context);
      //initialize notifications plugin settings
      await _initializeNotificationsSetttings();
      //call service to load a list of session data
      await TickersHelper.load();
      await _userDataController.loadSync(context, assinaturaController: _assinaturaController);
      _requestPermissions();
      _configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject();
      _configureSelectNotificationSubject();
      _loadAndSetTabIcons();
      await GetIt.I<UsuarioApiService>().callIncluirTokenPush();
      await GetIt.I<NotificacoesHelper>().programaNotifications(context);


      await _showDialogUmpCMP();
      await _autenticaBiometria();
      await _initDynamicLinks();

    } catch (ex, stack) {
       ....
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide more context (full stack trace and how your async method looks and how your future builder looks)? Also is your async init method taking a long time and would it be possible that you are navigating away of this widget (and therefor disposing the state) while your async method is still running?

Comment: #0      UserDataController.loadData (package:xxx/stores/user_data_controller.dart:213)<asynchronous suspension>#1      _HomePageState.getData (package:xxx/pages/home_page.dart:240)<asynchronous suspension>#2      _FutureBuilderState._subscribe.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:628)<asynchronous suspension>

Answer (score 0):

you can use didChangeDependencies lifecycle method instead of initState. In some cases, the context might not be fully initialized or available at the time the initState method is called, so By moving the initialization code to didChangeDependencies, you ensure that the context is available and ready to be used.

```
...
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();

  _userDataController = Provider.of<UserDataController>(context, listen: false);
  futureResult = getDataIni();
}

@override
void initState() {
...
```

other solution use WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback, I have used this Callback to execute  it works when the build is complete, I think it would work in your case too.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    _userDataController = Provider.of<UserDataController>(context, listen: false);
    futureResult = getDataIni();
  });
}
```

Comment: But the app cannot keep calling getDataIni() several times. What causes didChangeDependencies to run?
getDataIni can only run once on screen opening.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is wrong, when `initState` is called, the element is always inserted into the tree (and `mounted` is true), so the `context` will always be fully initialized inside of `initState`.

Comment: yes, didChangeDependencies is called multiple times. So, you need to handle potential multiple calls and this complicates more.

Comment: WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback, I think that with callback it should work fine for you in this case,

Comment: my bad for didChangeDependencies

Comment: All good, happens with that many different callbacks. And yes, using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` to modify a change notifier of a provider is always a good advice instead of doing it directly inside of `initState`. Although in this case i think his problem isn't modifying something too early, but rather too late, because his widget and state are somehow disposed by for example navigating away while his async init method is still running and so the context inside of that will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

for a better explanation i added a small code snippet:

```dart
class YourPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const YourPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<YourPage> createState() => _YourPageState();
}

class _YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {
  late Future<int> future;
  late Future<int> future2;

  Future<int> _someAsyncChain() async {
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    return Provider.of<int>(context, listen: false); // provider simulation
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    future = _someAsyncChain();
    future2 = _someAsyncChain(); // throws the exception
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("disposed");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<int>(
      future: future,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> data) {
        if (data.hasData) {
          return Text("DATA: ${data.data}");
        }
        return const Text("no data :(");
      },
    );
  }
}

Widget _build(BuildContext context) {
  bool showFirst = false;
  return StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        showFirst ? Provider<int>(create: (_) => 100, child: YourPage()) : Text("second page"),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => setState(() => showFirst = !showFirst), child: Text("change")),
      ],
    );
  });
}
```

I would guess something like this happens where you somehow dispose your State object faster than your load data future completes.

As you can see in this example, if you use the `change` button fast enough, the same exception is thrown, because the state is no longer available. But if you wait 3 seconds before pressing it, then everything is fine.

But without knowing your whole widget structure and the code of your `getDataIni` it is hard to say where exactly your error is.

This is also why in general it is not recommended to use `BuildContext` across async gaps.

But you are using the `context` of your `State` and your `FutureBuilder` is inside of your `State`, right? Because normally the future builder should be able to catch such an error (this is also why inside of my example above, the `future` does not throw the exception and only the `future2` does).

Are you using the newest flutter version?

Comment: I didn't understand your question about moving the future builder. What part of the code would be useful to help?

Comment: just explaining better, the exception occurs in this line await _userDataController.loadData(context); and not inside the loadData method

Comment: I editted my answer. Hope it explains it better now! Sadly i'll only be back and available again in like 18 hours fvrom now.

Comment: Niko . getting my provider in didChangeDependencies { _abaController = Provider.of<AbaController>(context, listen: false);} and passing it on is a bad practice? or can it give the same context error?

Comment: `didChangeDependencies` is only rarely used for some more expensive work that should be cached when the dependencies change that should not happen on every build call (the build method will also always be called afterwards). 

For accessing a provider with `Provider.of<AbaController>(context, listen: false)`  the correct way is to do that in `initState`, or any button `onPressed` callbacks.

Comment: Only if you change some values of a `ChangeNotifier` that your `Provider` provides, then these changes should not happen directly inside of `initState`, because the widget tree is currently building and you may not change data and notify for a new rebuild while the tree is already building. So for stuff like this use a microtask, or post frame callback.